# Generating XML Word Tables (Python)

Tags: python, xml, ms-word

Is there currently a way to generate XML files containing tables compatible with Microsoft Word? Preferably with python.

OR a way to generate MS word docs with python on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Microsoft word 2007 or later. In this case you can use python-docx library to read and write word files in python.

https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Comment: Works great so far on my Windows machine! Will check on Linux soon, thanks.

Comment: Just finished installing all the required dependencies, works on Linux thanks!!